# Disable Windows Touch Feedback in JavaFx application

Tags: java, windows, javafx, windows-runtime, touch

I am designing a canvas-based user application in JavaFX that requires users to draw with touch on their screen. The system uses a custom smoothing algorithm that I wrote in which the points that the user presses are not necessarily the exact points drawn on the screen. This would be fine BUT the windows visual touch feedback is incredibly distracting and must be disabled. I need a way to disable it just for this application rather than the entire OS.

Is this possible to do in java? Can I wrap my application or use some other injection/memory editing system to try and turn this feature off?

[image]

Here is a zoomed-in picture of the effect I wish to turn off:
[image]

Comment: From my understanding, the visual feedback is just the cursor with a particular icon, so if you disable/hide the cursor then it should solve your problem. This link should be helpful even though it is not JavaFX specific: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48074613/how-to-remove-white-touch-dot-on-windows-10

Comment: I did try hiding the cursor using the JavaFX setCursor(Cursor.None) method but to no avail